# How can I add a max length message with Jquery 'after' to a class of inputs and update it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get Jquery to append ('after') to some (class) of my inputs so the user knows how much more they can type. Is this even possible?

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".maxinputmessage") .after("<br><em>(Maximim characters: " + document.getElementById(this).maxLength + ") You have " + ( document.getElementById(this).maxLength - document.getElementById(this).Length) + " characters left.</em>");

});
</script>
```

with:

```
<label for="EditPVComment">PV Comments</label>
<textarea class="maxinputmessage" id="EditPVComment" name="EditPVComment" cols="80" rows="10" maxlength="3000" style="width:400px;">Some text here maybe.</textarea>
```

I got stuck with the maxLength and I would also like to update as they type and tell them how many characters they have left. (Is this to much for Jquery?) Thanks!

Comment: Nothing is too much for jQuery.

Comment: you can attach a key up event handler for your input that would check the length of the input field and display it to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. When inserting the element to display the remaining count, I would recommend including a `span` or a `div` tag holder that you can use to update the information during `"keyup"` bind event on the `textarea`

```
  <label for="EditPVComment">PV Comments</label>
<textarea class="maxinputmessage" id="EditPVComment" name="EditPVComment" cols="80" rows="10" maxlength="3000" style="width:400px;">Some text here maybe.</textarea>
<br>
<label for="EditManPVComment">Man PV Comments</label>
<textarea class="maxinputmessage" id="EditManPVComment" name="EditManPVComment" cols="80" rows="10" maxlength="3000" style="width:400px;">Some Man text here maybe.</textarea>

<script>
$().ready(function(){
              var $this = $(".maxinputmessage");

$this.each(function()
{
 var charMaxLen = $(this).attr("maxLength");
var charLen = $(this).val().length;

$(this).after("<em>(Maximim characters: " + charMaxLen + ") You have <span>" + (charMaxLen -     charLen)    +    "</span> characters left.</em>");

$(this).on("keyup",function()
{
    var charMaxLen = $(this).attr("maxLength");
    left = charMaxLen - $(this).val().length;
    $(this).next("em").find("span").text(charMaxLen - $(this).val().length);       
});
});

  });
</script>
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/rpcwt2ng/4/

Comment: This is very close to working. When I add another textarea it doesn't calculate the remaining characters properly. (Seems to use the original value)
Here: [link]http://jsfiddle.net/rpcwt2ng/

And I'm getting multiple lines of text. like:
(Maximim characters: 3000) You have 2993 characters left.
(Maximim characters: 3000) You have 2993 characters left.
(Maximim characters: 3000) You have 2993 characters left.

Comment: Since you have multiple textarea, you would need to iterate through each qualifying element and bind the events. Here's the example : http://jsfiddle.net/rpcwt2ng/2/. Updated the solution to reflect the changes

Comment: Nearly perfect! The initial remaining is the same in both. The bottom one should be different cause it has more text to start with. But as soon as I edit it, it is perfect!!

Comment: Great. Mark the solution as accepted if it solves the problem. Thanks

Comment: How can we solve the problem of: The initial remaining is the same in both. ?

Comment: move the scope of the variables from global to local. Check the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rpcwt2ng/4/ . Updated the solution as well

Comment: Working Great! I tried to add a br before the em and it stopped working. Then I added the br after the em and it works again. I don't get that!!

Comment: You need to add another .after to add a br. check this : http://jsfiddle.net/rpcwt2ng/5/

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="ipText" />
Remaining <span id="remaining"></span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
  var limit = 50;
    $("#ipText").keyup(function() {
       $("#remaining").text(limit - $("#ipText").val().length);    
    });
```

Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lcfwgvxb/1/)